# Handling Indeterminate Forms

Tags: functions

I'm running a sum, the elements of which are calculated by calling functions that I wrote. The only issue is, I've implemented this pretty stupid solution where I have 4 or 5 (nested!) if statements to handle cases where mathematica returns `Indeterminate` when it should be returning "0". What I'm essentially looking for is some kind of "If" statement that returns either 0 if Mathematica returns `Indeterminate`, and evaluates to something I have implemented already otherwise.

Any ideas? I've tried using combinations of the `If`/ `Check` functions, without too much luck.

**Summary:** I'm trying to write an `If` statement that checks for `Indeterminate` values, and returns one of two values. Any ideas?

Comment: `Indeterminate` is a special head. When you use `If`, you need to use `===` or `SameQ` instead of `==` or `Equal` to test if something is `Indeterminate`. All of this is in the documentation for [`Indeterminate`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpjgui6-cobwly).

Comment: Btw, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Could you try to invent a more memorable user name? All those userxxxxxs are no fun.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you just need a replace operation?

```
0 / {3, 2, 1, 0}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, Indeterminate}
> ```

```
% /. Indeterminate -> 0
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

`If` has a 4-argument version in which the fourth argument is returned in cases where the condition yield `Indeterminate`.