# How to Override a Calculated Value in a Matrix with an Assigned Value

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How do I override a calculated value within a matrix with an assigned value? Here is an example of what I mean. Consider matrix Y,

```
Y = MatrixForm[Table[i^j,{i, 0, 1, 0.5}, {j, 0, 2, 1}]]
```

with the output

[image]

Of course, the `Indeterminate` in `Y[1, 1]`is due to `0^0`. How do I override the `Indeterminate` output with say `Y[1, 1] = 1` while creating the matrix?
Thank you.

Comment: A few things, 1) `MatrixForm` is a wrapper, you probably want `MatrixForm[ Y = Table[ .... ] ] ` 2) Parts are taken and assigned with `Part` which has an alias in `[[ ]]` so what in a more classic C-derived language would be `Y[1, 1]` in Mathematica is `Y[[1, 1]]`. So all together you want `Y = Table[ ... ]; Y[[1,1]]=1; MatrixForm[Y]`.

Comment: If[i==j==0,1,i^j]

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you for the tweak. Your suggestion works pretty fine.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(10977)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10977/121), [(60575)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60575/121), [(64179)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64179/121), [(102007)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102007/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if you don't know in advance where `Indeterminate` entries are going to appear, you can use `/.` (`ReplaceAll`) to replace them with whatever you like. So

```
Y = Table[i^j, {i, 0, 1, 0.5}, {j, 0, 2, 1}];
(* {{Indeterminate, 0., 0.}, {1., 0.5, 0.25}, {1., 1., 1.}} *)
```

Then

```
Y /. {Indeterminate -> 1} 
(* {{1, 0., 0.}, {1., 0.5, 0.25}, {1., 1., 1.}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, there is some undocumented functionality for generating [Vandermonde matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VandermondeMatrix.html):

```
LinearAlgebra`VandermondeMatrix[{0, 0.5, 1}, Transpose -> True]
   {{1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0.5, 0.25}, {1., 1., 1.}}
```

---

**Edit 7/19/2022**

In the current version, the following should be evaluated instead:

```
StructuredArray`VandermondeMatrix[{0, 0.5, 1}, List]
```

Answer (score 4):

Also

```
Block[{Indeterminate = 1}, Quiet@Table[i^j, {i, 0, 1, 0.5}, {j, 0, 2, 1}]] 
   // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0. & 0. \\
>  1. & 0.5 & 0.25 \\
>  1. & 1. & 1. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$